# discord bot does not display a message in the console

Tags: discord.py, python-3.12

```
from discord.ext import commands
import data_bot

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return  # Ігнорує повідомлення від інших ботів

    print(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run(data_bot.TOKEN)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiBkJ.png)
I am a beginner in programming and wanted to write a Discord bot that would display all messages that were on the server in the console. Unfortunately, the bot does not output the text itself. I do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the message content privileged [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents). Without this, all messages will be empty. This has to be both enabled in the code, and in the developer portal.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

And on the developer portal, where you first created your bot:
[image: Intents enabled on the dev portal]